# всплывающая форма jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть форма с `display:none`

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
  <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="+79999999"><br>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

надо сделать так чтобы при клике по кнопке с классом `.form-popup`
форма появлялась, делал так

```
$(".form-popup").click(function() {
  $("#form").show();
});
```

не получилось...

Answer (score 0):

Да вроде нормально всё

```js
$(".form-popup").click(function() {
  $("#form").show();
});
```

```css
#form{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
  <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="+79999999"><br>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
<button class="form-popup">Показать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Баг в jQuery, когда стиль задан для `form`:

```js
$(".form-popup").click(function() {
  $("#form").show();
});
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="form-popup">Click</button>
<form id="form">
  <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
  <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="+79999999"><br>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

При этом, так работает:

```
$("#form").css("display", "block");
```

и так работает - с инлайн стилем:

```
<form id="form" style="display: none;">
...
$("#form").show();
```

Нет бага в 3.1.1:

```js
$(".form-popup").click(function() {
  $("#form").show();
});
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="form-popup">Click</button>
<form id="form">
  <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
  <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="+79999999"><br>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: К сожалению ни один из вариантов не подошел, пробывал даже так сделать,     $("#form").hide();
     $(".form-popup").click(function() {
       $("#form").show();

      })

Comment: Думаю на крайний случай попробовать реализовать на какой нибудь библиотеке типа fancybox

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не обернуть форму дивом и диву повесить `#form`?

```js
$('.form-popup').on('click',()=>{
  $('#form').show();
});
```

```css
#form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
    <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="+79999999"><br>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>

<input class="form-popup" type="button" value="show">
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может возникнуть из-за того, что ваш jQuery-скрипт выполняется до того, как HTML-страница полностью загружена. Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, убедитесь, что код выполняется после полной загрузки страницы. Вот пример, как вы можете это сделать:

````
```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Всплывающая форма</title>
  <!-- Подключаем jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #form {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="+79999999"><br>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </form>

  <!-- Добавляем класс form-popup к кнопке -->
  <button class="form-popup">Открыть форму</button>

  <script>
    // Обертываем код в $(document).ready()
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".form-popup").click(function() {
        $("#form").show();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```
````

Обратите внимание, что я добавил `type="text"` для полей ввода с именем и телефоном, так как `type="name"` и `type="number"` не существует.